# How to bind a controller action to a model from a referenced dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, model-binding

I am trying to POST JSON to a controller action in my .NET Core project.

The relevant controller action:

```
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]PrivateModel value) {/*Process value*/}
```

The problem is that `PrivateModel` is from a referenced dll. As such, the automatic model binding is failing, `value` is always null.

I believe it's a factor of the model not being local because if I create a copy of the structure of `PrivateModel` in my project and use that instead, the data is bound correctly. Using this stripped-down copy is not a workable solution because I need to use functions of `PrivateModel`.

Is there a way for me to make the model binding work with a referenced class?

Comment: Does PrivateModel and all its properties have correct visibility (say nothing is internal)?

Comment: You could derive from PrivateModel and use that if it is acceptable.

Comment: @Andrei Yes, all of it's properties have correct visibility

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius Using a derived class may be what I end up having to do, but it is not ideal.

Comment: It makes no difference if `PrivateModel` is in a separate dll. If its not binding its dues to other issues with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Stephen Muecke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48644600/how-to-bind-a-controller-action-to-a-model-from-a-referenced-dll#comment84302970_48644600) was correct. Trying to bind a model from a referenced dll was not the issue.

There was an error in the custom JSON serializer that `PrivateModel` was using that kept the model from being constructed. My local copies did not run into this error since I did not specify that they should use the custom serializer.

Once the serializer bug was fixed, the model binding worked correctly with no further changes to my code.

Answer (score 0):

=> Take look into code, this reference purpose.

1. Your API Controller, Parameter name is as same as ajax data such like **[ data: param ]** parameter
2. Your Json post data member is as same as your reference dll class properties.

API Controller

```
//Also you can use ActionResult
public HttpResponseMessage controller(Parameter param)
{
    return Json // Return Json
}
```

Reference DLL class For Example

```
public class Parameter
{
    public string publish { get; set; }
    public string user { get; set; }
}
```

Javascript Function on Button click like

```
 function RunDemand() {
    var param = '{ publish : "On Demand",user : "Ankit" }';
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/controller",
        type: "POST",
        data: param,
        contentType: "application/json; charset = utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                //Do Process
            }
            else {
                //Do Process
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What on earth does this have to do this the question